# In C#, how can I filter a list using a StartsWith() condition of another list?

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Lets say I have a list of strings:

```
var searchList = new List<string>();
searchList.Add("Joe"):
searchList.Add("Bob");
```

and I have another list

```
var fullNameList = new List<string>();
fullNameList.Add("Joe Thompson"):
fullNameList.Add("Bob Jones");
fullNameList.Add("Bob Smith");
fullNameList.Add("Billy Smith");
fullNameList.Add("Joe Williams");
```

I now want to filter the fullNameList based on if it exists in the search list but I am not doing a direct match but rather a "starts with" match.  So in my example, after filtering I would want this to be the results

```
"Joe Thompson"
"Bob Jones"
"Bob Smith"
"Joe Williams"
```

(as you can see the record starting with Billy was not included as it didn't start with any items in the search list)

I could do this "manually" like this:

```
 var resultList = fullNameList.Where(r=> r.StartsWith("Joe") || r.StartsWith("Bob"));
```

but I want it to be dynamic (as there might be more items in the search list added in the future).

I could do this in a loop like this:

```
 var resultsList = new List<string>();

 foreach (var item in searchList)
 { 
      resultsList.AddRange(fullNameList.Where(r=>r.StartsWith(item));
 }
```

but wanted to see if there anyway to do a Startswith on a list as opposed to a single string in a single line of linq code?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
var resultList = fullNameList.Where(r => searchList.Any(f=>r.StartsWith(f)));
```

Comment: Nice one!! sometimes its easy but isn't coming to mind initially!!

Answer (score 3):

Something like:

```
fullNameList.Where(c=>searchList.Any(f=>c.StartsWith(f)))
```

Answer (score 3):

The following LINQ query seems literate-programming-like to me and pretty straightforward to read & maintain later,:

```
var searchList = new List<string> { "Joe", "Bob" };

var fullNameList = new List<string>
    {
        "Joe Thompson",
        "Bob Jones",
        "Bob Smith",
        "Billy Smith",
        "Joe Williams"
    };

var joesAndBobs = from name in fullNameList
                  from firstName in searchList
                  where name.StartsWith(firstName)
                  select name;

foreach (string str in joesAndBobs)
    Console.WriteLine(str);
```

However, it may perform worse than solutions previously posted. They use `.Any()` method of `IEnumerable<T>`, it stops after finding the first matching first name for any dude, while mine continues through all the Joes, Bobs and Mikes anyway.