# [Azure Deployments]: Can we filter Azure Resource Group Deployments by name using c#?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-deployment

I am trying to fetch the Azure Resource Group Deployments by using **filter where name starting with "Deploy"** but can't find any documentation on the $filter.

I tried to do something like below:

```
try
{
    var credentials = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
    var resourceClient = new ResourcesManagementClient(subscriptionId, credentials);
    var deployments = resourceClient.Deployments;
    AsyncPageable<DeploymentExtended> rgDeployments = deployments.ListByResourceGroupAsync("myRG", "name eq 'Deploy-20210412184314'");
    await foreach (DeploymentExtended deploymentProperties in rgDeployments)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(deploymentProperties.Name);
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Trace.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

But it gives error saying -

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidProvisioningStateFilter","message":"Invalid $filter 'name eq 'Deploy-20210412184314'' specified in the query string."}}
```

So can we only use filter like `provisioningState eq '{state}'` not for name?

I am using [Azure Resources Management client library for .NET](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources_1.0.0-preview.2/sdk/resources/Azure.ResourceManager.Resources/README.md).

Please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.resources.deploymentsoperations.listbyresourcegroupasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview).

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid you could not use the filter with `name eq 'Deploy-20210412184314'`, in this case, if you already knew the name of the deployment and want to get it at the resource group scope, no need to use `ListByResourceGroupAsync`, just use this method [`DeploymentsOperations.GetAsync(String, String, CancellationToken)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.resources.deploymentsoperations.getasync?view=azure-dotnet-preview), pass the `resourceGroupName` and `deploymentName`, you can simply get it.

Comment: I want to filter with name starting with deploy but I do not find any documentation on how to use it that why for example I gave that name. Yes you are right we can use GetAsync in that case.

Comment: @JagratiModi I don't think it supports filter with name, the method calls this [rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/Deployments/ListByResourceGroup), if you test the filter directly in this api, it also not work. Besides, if you test with the powershell `Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName "xxxx" -Name "xxxx"`(it also calls the api), catch the request, you will find anyway the name was passed to the request url directly instead of `$filter`.

Comment: @JagratiModi So if you want to filter where name starting with "Deploy", just do it locally with C#, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29577639/in-c-how-can-i-filter-a-list-using-a-startswith-condition-of-another-list

Comment: @JagratiModi Any other concerns about this issue?

Comment: Hey @Joy Wang Thanks! I also thought about Client side filtering but was curious to know if there is any use of this filter in case. I will look into it. Thanks!

Comment: @JagratiModi Did you have any update on this issue?;-)