# Get files names with multiple extensions by a list of strings

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, filenames

In a VSTO solution I have a List of(Strings):

```
AA000017
FF100218
P0100217
DF100216
CODICE - CODE
A010AA77
B0000017
```

In a folder I have many file with different extensions, for example I have:

```
DF100216.DXF
DF100216.DWG
DF100216.PDF
DF100216.STP
FF100218.PDF
FF100218_00-001.PDF
FF100218_00-002.PDF
FF100218_00-003.PDF
FF100218.STP
ecc
```

This for each value of the list. If I need for example the pdf files with code FF100218, I need back a lsit whit :

```
FF100218.PDF
FF100218_00-001.PDF
FF100218_00-002.PDF
FF100218_00-003.PDF
```

I have a code like this:

```
Dim SelectedtList As New List(Of String) {"DF100216","FF100218","DF100216"}
Dim DrawingExtensionList() As String = {"*.PDF","*.TIF"} 
 For Each ext In DrawingExtensionList
                            'Returns only the filenames based on the directory that is selected
                            Dim fi = From f In New IO.DirectoryInfo(DrowingPath_Internal).GetFiles(ext).Cast(Of IO.FileInfo)()
                                     Where fi.Name Like SelectedtList
                                     Select f
                            fileList.AddRange(fi)
                        Next
```

There is a way to do this?

Comment: Try _Directory.GetFiles("FF100218*.*")_

Comment: Yes, with GetFiles I have the result I need but only for one extension. If I need all the documents for a code, it dosn't work. I have a query that work with the files extensions, but I'm not able to make the modificatione for reading also the code.

Comment: No, not for just one extension. If you use ".*" then you'll get every extension. Maybe you actually mean for one pattern. The obvious solution is to call `GetFiles` multiple times, once for each pattern. That's what loops are for.

Comment: Sorry it is Directory.GetFiles(path, "FF100218*.*"); In the pattern parameter you could use the * to ignore whatever is present after the prefix and whatever is the extension

Comment: The problem with using getfile too many times is that it becomes too slow for me. This operation can be made a lot of times...

Comment: Then use EnumerateFiles with the same parameters but it doesn't load all files in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [In C#, how can I filter a list using a StartsWith() condition of another list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29577639/1115360), you could do this:

```
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim files = {"DF100216.DXF", "DF100216.DWG", "DF100216.PDF", "DF100216.STP", "FF100218.PDF", "FF100218_00-001.PDF", "FF100218_00-002.PDF", "FF100218_00-003.PDF", "FF100218.STP", "ecc"}
        Dim selectedList = {"DF100216", "FF100218", "DF100216"}
        Dim drawingExtensionList() As String = {".pdf", ".TIF"}

        Dim fileList = files.Where(Function(f) selectedList.Any(Function(s) Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f).StartsWith(s, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) AndAlso
                                               drawingExtensionList.Any(Function(w) String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(f), w, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0))).ToList()

        Console.WriteLine(String.Join(vbCrLf, fileList))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

N.B.: It uses the file extension such as ".pdf", not the wildcard-style "*.pdf".

To get:

```
DF100216.PDF
FF100218.PDF
FF100218_00-001.PDF
FF100218_00-002.PDF
FF100218_00-003.PDF
```

To make it work from the directory instead of setting it to an array like in the above example, you can use:

```
Dim files = Directory.EnumerateFiles("your\full\path\here")
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254362/discussion-between-gianfranco-vrech-and-andrew-morton).